# Trigger function in different screen in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to set the visibility of my modal in the `NotificationsModal` to true by pressing on a notifications icon in the `Nav` class.

```
class Nav extends Component {
    constructor(){
      super()
      this.state={
        show: false,
      } 
    }

    showNotifications(){
      this.setState({
        show: true
      })
    }

    render() { 
        const logo = '../../../assets/logo2.png';
        return ( 
            <View style={styles.top}>
              <NotificationsModal visible={this.state.show}/>
                <View style={styles.emptyLeft}>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.logo}>
                  <Image source= {require(logo)} style={{ width: 100, height: 60, marginTop: 20,}} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.icon}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.showNotifications()}>
                  <Bell name="bell" size={30} color="white" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
         );
    }}export default Nav;
```

And here is the class that contains the modal

```
    class NotificationsModal extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            modalVisible: false,
        }
        this.modalVisibility = this.modalVisibility.bind(this)
    }

    modalVisibility(visible) {
        this.setState({
            modalVisible: visible
        })
    }

    render() { 
        return ( 
            <Modal transparent={true} animationType="fade" visible={this.state.modalVisible}>
                <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center',backgroundColor: "#7b7b7aaa",}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1}} activeOpacity={1}  
                        onPress={() => this.modalVisibility(false)}>
                        <View style={styles.TriangleShapeView}/>
                        <View style={styles.modal}>
                            <ScrollView>
                                <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                                    <View style={styles.notificationsBox}>
                                        <Text>Hi</Text>
                                        <Text>Hi</Text>
                                        <Text>Hi</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                            </ScrollView>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </Modal>
         );
    }}export default NotificationsModal;
```

I cannot set the visible prop in the modal component to `this.props.show` because the `TouchableOpacity` on the `NotificationsModal` class has the capability to control the state. So technically, the only solution is to call the function `modalVisibilty` when the icon in the `Nav` class is pressed. however, I am unsure how to do that.

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn `NotificationsModal` into Presentational Component and move its state to `Nav` Component.

```
class Nav extends Component {
    constructor(){
      super()
      this.state = {
        show: false,
        modalVisible: false,
      }

      this.modalVisibility = this.modalVisibility.bind(this)
    }

    modalVisibility(visible) {
      this.setState(state => ({
        ...state,
        modalVisible: visible
      }))
    }

    showNotifications() {
      this.setState(state => ({
         ...state,
         show: true
      })
    }

    render() { 
        const logo = '../../../assets/logo2.png';
        return ( 
            <View style={styles.top}>
              <NotificationsModal modalVisible={modalVisible} modalVisibility={this.modalVisibility} visible={this.state.show}/>
                <View style={styles.emptyLeft}>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.logo}>
                  <Image source= {require(logo)} style={{ width: 100, height: 60, marginTop: 20,}} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.icon}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.showNotifications()}>
                  <Bell name="bell" size={30} color="white" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
         );
    }}

export default Nav;
```

```
render() { 
        return ( 
            <Modal transparent={true} animationType="fade" visible={this.props.modalVisible}>
                <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center',backgroundColor: "#7b7b7aaa",}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1}} activeOpacity={1}  
                        onPress={() => this.props.modalVisibility(false)}>
                        <View style={styles.TriangleShapeView}/>
                        <View style={styles.modal}>
                            <ScrollView>
                                <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                                    <View style={styles.notificationsBox}>
                                        <Text>Hi</Text>
                                        <Text>Hi</Text>
                                        <Text>Hi</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                            </ScrollView>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </Modal>
         );
```

Comment: unfortunatly this is not working for me, the functions in the Nav class are showing errors, should there be any code instead of the three dots?